# How to show different element based on selected language in l18n in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

I have an angular app. I am using two languages (English and Urdu) to show texts. English uses ltr and Urdu uses rtl way to display text. Now, I want to add an *ngif in a  to show some element only in English. If Urdu language I selected, I want to use the else-block of *ngif. What should I pass to *ngif as check , to get the desired result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I googled much and also checked with stack overflow, if I get related questions. When, I didn't get the solution, then only I asked this question here.

Comment: Which module are you using for translations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getDefaultLang()` method to retrieve the language used.

Within your component :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: 'template.html'
})
export class YourComponent {

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    }

    rightToLeftText(){
       // RightToLeft text if language is equal to Urdu
       return this.translate.getDefaultLang() == "urd";
    }

}
```

And in your template :

```
<div *ngIf="rightToLeftText()">Right to left</div>
<div *ngIf="!rightToLeftText()">Not right to left</div>
```